# Android TV showing "There was a problem communicating with Google servers, try again later" error

Tags: google-play-store, android-tv

I just got a new Android TV box and am trying to sign into Google play store but every time I put in the information and hit enter the error "There was a problem communicating with Google servers, try again later" pops up. I have cleared the data on Google play store and Google play services and have restarted my TV but nothing works. What should I do? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps there's an update available for your TV?  Have you tried navigating to Settings and finding a System Update page?

Comment: I checked. There's no update. My system is up to date.